# how-to apache 2.2 mod_fcgid set python path

Tags: python, apache2, environment-variables, mod-fcgid

i have trouble with seting the python path or any other enviroment variable for mod_fcgid (solaris 10, glassfish apache 2.2)

I have it set in apache, but nothing in os.environ in the fcgi script:

```
SetEnv PYTHONPATH "/opt/uusis/lib/python2.4/site-packages/:/usr/lib/python2.4/"
```

And other stuff(for example ORACLE_HOME) and I need to access them in the fcgi script.
I know i can use this to set the python path.

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/uusis/lib/python2.4/site-packages")
sys.path.insert(1, "/usr/lib/python2.4/")
```

Is there a way to pass the enviroment values from apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Solaris 10 glassfish apache 2.2 mod_fcgid has "DefaultInitEnv"

This is not documented in the apache mod_fcgid ...

Example:

```
DefaultInitEnv PYTHONPATH "/opt/something/lib/python2.4/site-packages/:/usr/lib/python2.4/"
```

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure if this help. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/env.html